# Binding nested objects doesn't work

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin

Dear friends i have this trouble.

I'm building my first from in vaadin.

I have the followed Object Model

```
public class Utente {

private String nome;
private String cognome;

private Indirizzo indirizzo;


public Utente() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    indirizzo = new Indirizzo();
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getCognome() {
    return cognome;
}

public void setCognome(String cognome) {
    this.cognome = cognome;
}

public Indirizzo getIndirizzo() {
    return indirizzo;
}

public void setIndirizzo(Indirizzo indirizzo) {
    this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
}

}
```

This is my Form

```
mainLayout = new FormLayout();
    fieldGroup = new FieldGroup();
    utente = new Utente();
    beanUtente = new BeanItem<Utente>(utente);

    TextField nomeField = new TextField("Nome");
    mainLayout.addComponent(nomeField);

    TextField cognomeField = new TextField("Cognome");
    mainLayout.addComponent(cognomeField);

    TextField viaField = new TextField("Via");
    viaField.setWidth("350px");
    mainLayout.addComponent(viaField);

    TextField comuneField = new TextField("Comune");
    mainLayout.addComponent(comuneField);

    TextField provinciaField = new TextField("Provincia");
    mainLayout.addComponent(provinciaField);

    TextField capField = new TextField("Cap");
    mainLayout.addComponent(capField);

    button = new Button("Salva Utente");
    mainLayout.addComponent(button);

    fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(beanUtente);

    fieldGroup.bind(nomeField,"nome");
    fieldGroup.bind(cognomeField,"cognome");
    fieldGroup.bind(viaField, "indirizzo.via");
    fieldGroup.bind(comuneField, "indirizzo.comune");
    fieldGroup.bind(provinciaField, "indirizzo.provincia");
    fieldGroup.bind(capField, "indirizzo.cap");

    fieldGroup.setBuffered(false);
```

Now when i try to bind the components at the model, i showed the followed error:

**Property type for 'indirizzo.via' could not be determined. No property with that id was found.**

Where i wrong?

Comment: Why are you handling "Via" differently with `buildAndBind`? You've treated it just like the rest in the above code. Just something I noticed not sure if it's intentional.

Comment: Solved :) , i had to use the BeanFieldGroup instead of FieldGroup

Comment: Feel free to write a good answer explaining your changes and such and accept it.

Comment: @PropertyId+FieldGroup+Jpacontainer does not work for me I had to use a CustomField

Comment: @JuanRojas Open a new question where you explain your trouble in more detailed way